# Create list of zeroes/ones based on whether index is contained in a list of intervals

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of lists, each indicating a numeric interval:

```
intervals = [[1, 4],
             [7, 9],
             [13, 18]
             ]
```

I need to create a list of 20 elements, where each element is 0 if its index is NOT contained in any of the intervals, and 1 otherwise. So, the desired output is:

```
output = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

I can think of using something simple, in the lines of:

```
output = zeros(20)
for index, _ in enumerate(output):
    for interval in intervals:
        if interval[0] <= index <= interval[1]:
            output[index] = 1
```

but is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Is your list of intervals guaranteed to be sorted as you've shown in your example?

Comment: Yes, it is. There can be a variable number of intervals, but they are sorted.

Comment: You could store the upper bound and lower bound of the visited/processed intervals and then before processing a new interval, check the stored bounds and avoid processing the current interval if it is already covered. This is an optimization for your existing solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially the same as @mozway's answer, but without creating an intermediate data structure and arguably more readable:

```
output = np.zeros(N, dtype=int)

for start, end in intervals:
    output[np.arange(start, end+1)] = 1
```

Comment: It's psychological, I am very reluctant to use a for loop with numpy, the list comprehension is my threshold :p

Answer (score 3):

You could use advanced indexing:

```
a = np.zeros(20, dtype=int)

idx = np.hstack([np.r_[a:b+1] for a,b in intervals])
# array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  7,  8,  9, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18])

a[idx] = 1
```

output:

```
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```

Comment: You are iterating just as much as @Marat. Only timings can say which is faster.

Comment: @hpaulj I know, I never said otherwise ;) I just liked it this way. Btw, would you know how to programmatically perform a `np.r_[a:b, c:d,...]` from a list of `[[a,b], [c,d], ...]` unpacking can't be used in `[...]`

Comment: You can give it a tuple of slices, `np.r_[tuple([slice(a,b) for a,b in intervals])]`.  While `r_` is clever, I haven't found it to be faster.   A simple `arange` is faster: `np.hstack([np.arange(x, y) for x, y in intervals])`

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more efficient way to do this, but this might get you started:

```
intervals = np.array([[1, 4], [7, 9], [13, 18]])
low, high = intervals[:,0], intervals[:,1]

r = np.arange(20)[:,None]
((low <= r) & (high >= r)).any(1).astype(int)
```

output:

```
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0])
```